# Optional route parameters being enforced in php Slim Framework v4

Tags: php, api, slim, fastroute

I'm using slim 4. I may be misunderstanding optional route parameters. My code is below:

```php
public function __invoke(App $app)
{
    $app->post('/login', LoginHandler::class);
    $app->get('/users/{id:\d+}', UserHandler::class);
}
```

I expected `/users/` to be a valid route as would `/users/1`, but I find `/users/` can't resolve, and I get a 404.  I am I misinterpreting the word "optional" here.  Cant find anything in any of the slim documentation nor on stackoverflow.

I really didn't want to have to go with the following:

```php
$app->get('/user/{id:\d+}', UserHandler::class);
$app->get('/users/', UserHandler::class);
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional parameters need `[]` (from https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/routing.html#optional-segments), so...

```
$app->get('/users/[{id:\d+}]', UserHandler::class);
```

Comment: Cant believe i didnt see this.  I really need glasses.  That page on routing is confusing as the top talks a lot about optional parameters and shows examples with only {}   In any case, thats it now working.  Thanks so much for taking time to look at my question

Comment: Thanks for flagging this.  I've now marked this answer as accepted